# how to turn off these PHP warnings?

Tags: php, warnings

run.php is just a normal PHP file:

```
[root@www4 robot]# php run.php 
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DISKIO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (LM-SENSORS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-ICMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
```

Comment: Can you please post your OS? It may help giving instructions for you to install the SNMP MIB libraries and/or update your PHP configuration if needed.

Comment: I had the same problem. For some reason I had the SNMP module enabled to load in php.ini. Commented that line out of php.ini and its fine now.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this post](http://bytes.com/groups/php/453256-cannot-find-module-error-messages-php#post1733682), you don't have the proper SNMP management information bases installed. Install the correct package for your linux distribution, something like *net-snmp*.

Answer (score 6):

I've just turned off snmp extension

Comment: for others... this is found in the php.ini file - extension=php_snmp.dll

Answer (score 2):

When something gives you errors, the worst approach is to just "turn them off".  If the emergency light turns on in your car dashboard, do you go get it services or do you unscrew the light bulbs?!

Comment: There's a big difference between just turning off errors and turning off the thing-you're-not-using that's _causing_ the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Reason have by PHP extensions. 
You try:

```
Open Setup PHP file.
In setting PHP extensions removed extensions below:
   - PostgreSQL
   - Shared Memo....
   - SNMP
   - SOAP
   - SQLite
   - SQLite 3
```

Reference:
http://blog.vnlives.net/2013/10/php-bug-no-log-handling-enabled-turning.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is a windows setup you can go to `add/remove programs` (or `program features`) and do a **change** in the PHP program and under `choose item to install` make sure you deselect extention `SNMP` and other extentions you don't need.

Finish the installer wizard. After that do an `iisreset`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your php.ini file is misconfigured to load modules that don't exist.